# How to derive Additive generically on Haskell, without defining an Applicative instance?

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, haskell-linear

Given a type, there is only one obvious way to implement an `Additive` instance, from the Linear library, to it. Conveniently, `Additive` has a generic implementation, so we can use `deriving` for it. Unfortunately, it depends on the existence of an `Applicative` instance, which is not derivable, so you still have to declare it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveFunctor #-}

import Linear
import GHC.Generics
import Control.Applicative

data Foo a = Foo a a a deriving (Show, Functor, Generic1)

instance Additive Foo

instance Applicative Foo where
    pure x = Foo x x x
    Foo f g h <*> Foo x y z = Foo (f x) (g y) (h z)

main = print $ Foo 1 2 3 ^+^ Foo 4 5 6
```

Is there any way to derive Additive automatically, without having to declare an Applicative instance?

Comment: In next version of base 4.17.0.0, `GHC.Generics` will add a newtype called `Generically1`. This has an `Applicative` instance for any generic product type constructor. `data Foo a = Foo a a a deriving stock Generic1 deriving (Functor, Applicative) via Generically1 Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

The canonical example of a datatype which has two perfectly cromulent `Applicative` instances is `[]` / `ZipList`. This proves that a generic derivation of `Applicative` for `[]` would need to somehow choose one or the other, when in fact neither choice is more valid than the other.